# flutter issue in video player

Tags: flutter, video-player

I am trying to play a recorded video using flutter videoplayer plugin.
Sometime video is recorded and played successfully and sometime i see below error
Same issue is happening on simulator too. I have checked the video and it does exists.

I am using chewie player plugin and player code is

```
 _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoController,
      autoPlay: false,
      looping: false,

    );

    _chewieController != null &&
                                        _chewieController
                                            .videoPlayerController.value.initialized
                                    ? Chewie(
                                        controller: _chewieController,
                                      )
                                    : Container()
```

and ERROR is below

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl(24623): Init f37628f [ExoPlayerLib/2.12.1] [dreamlte, SM-G950F, samsung, 28]
I/OMXClient(24623): IOmx service obtained
E/ACodec  (24623): Unable to instantiate codec 'OMX.Exynos.avc.dec' with err 0xfffffff4.
E/ACodec  (24623): signalError(omxError 0xfffffff4, internalError -12)
E/MediaCodec(24623): Codec reported err 0xfffffff4, actionCode 0, while in state 1
W/MediaCodec-JNI(24623): try to release MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec()...
W/MediaCodec-JNI(24623): done releasing MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec().
W/MediaCodecRenderer(24623): Failed to initialize decoder: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec
```

Comment: Do you use a chewie plugin? And could you provide the part of code with your video player widget?

Comment: Yes and i have updated my  question for that part of a code.